# Possible to download the past 12 month of Slashdot frontpage stories?

Tags: linux, download-manager, parser, rss

I haven't read Slashdot and SoylentNews for the past year, and would like to catch up of what I missed.

## Question

Is there a Linux program that can fetch/download the past 12 months of front pages stories of Slashdot and/or SoylentNews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Slashdot you can fetch the page for a particular day with a url in the format:

```
https://slashdot.org/?issue=20200110
```

Where in this example the `?issue=` is followed by a date in the format YYYYMMDD and using this I was able to go back to the beginning of 2000.

You can further filter it to a topic, *in this example to the topic technology,* by using the format:

```
https://technology.slashdot.org/?issue=20200416
```

Possible topics are:

- devices
- build
- entertainment
- technology
- opensource
- science
- yro

Knowing this it is perfectly possible to manually, in a browser or using wget, to view the  summary pages for each day. Of course for a whole year this would take a bit of typing so I would suggest automating this with a [python](https://python.org) script. However, please respect the loading of the servers by taking some time, *(and ideally running during a  quiet time).*

There are a number of ways to do this but I would suggest using [requests-html](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) or possibly [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) but if you are using requests_html don't forget to have a time.sleep between page fetches.

Example using requests-html that should get this years headlines as a summary page with the links to the headlines:

```
#! usr/bin python3
import time
import datetime
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url_base = "https://technology.slashdot.org/?issue=%04d%02d%02d"
start_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1) # Start new years day
day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

session = HTMLSession()
url_base = "https://technology.slashdot.org/?issue=%s"

outfile = open("headlines.html", "wb")
# Put a html header in
outfile.write(b"""<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
 <head> 
 <title>title</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="description" content="" /> <meta name="keywords" content="" /> 
 <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" /> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
 </head>  
 <body>""")
theday = start_date
def mkheader(aday):
    """ Header for a day """
    return b"<h1>%s</h1>\n" % aday.strftime('%D-%m-%d').encode('utf-8')

while theday < datetime.datetime.now():
    page = session.get(url_base % theday.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
    elements = page.html.find('h2.story')
    outfile.write(mkheader(theday))
    for e in elements:
        outfile.write(e.html.replace('href="//', 'href="https://').encode())
        outfile.write(b"\n")
    theday += day
    time.sleep(10) # Ten seconds delay might need to add a random element

outfile.write(b"</body>\n</html>")
outfile.close()
```

Comment: The script fails for me. I get `  File "s.py", line 25 for e in elements:` and `  File "s.py", line 26 outfile.write(e.raw_html)`

Comment: @SandraSchlichting: Sorry there was a missing ) on line 24.

Comment: Now I get: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s.py", line 30, in <module>
    page = session.get(url_base % theday.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
NameError: name 'session' is not defined
`

Comment: Missing line added! Sorry, pasting error. Also fixing up links for each headline.